# Auto vacuum for table ASAP

Tags: postgresql, vacuum, autovacuum

In my app for Postgresql I have a table and my app inserts rows to that table. It could be 2-3 rows, also it could be 100-200k rows. How to do that auto vacuum runs for that table as soon as possible? I played with **autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor**, **autovacuum_analyze_threshold** and other parameters for this table but didn't get good results.
Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure `auto vacuum daemon` is enabled or not. The parameters you are currently tweaking is for `ANALYSE` which is supposed to run after  vacuuming. For vacuum control mainly below two params are used,

`autovacuum_vacuum_threshold`(Default:50 rows)

`autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor`(Default:20 % of table size)

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-autovacuum.html